# Ruby: Running Gosu game from a web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opalrb, libgosu

So what I want to do is this:

- User visits www.website.com
- There is a button called "play game"
- Gosu game (which I have already written) will launch the window.
- User can play game.

so maybe it'll look like this:

```
<button type = "submit" > PLAY GAME </button>
<iframe><%= MyGameFile.rb.execute %></iframe>
<!-- Iframe will contain the window of the Gosu app -->
```

I've been reading around and I've seen that there may be a way to trick it into running by using Jruby. I've also thought that maybe it would be a good idea to use Opal to recompile the Ruby code into JS and maybe somehow run it that way.

But to avoid confusion, the question is: Is it possible to implement the steps above? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: seems highly improbable that you can transpile the whole gosu framework using opal. Gosu uses c / cpp libs...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking :/ I think i've heard of some new google technology that allows you to run apps natively on the browser with c++. Maybe i'll go thru that avenue