# Ruby Gosu: How to generate a shareable (WebGL, executable) version of my game?

Tags: ruby, executable, libgosu

I am doing some game using Ruby Gosu and I will like to share then on the internet. I have been reading that generating a WebGL version of them [it is still not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255825/embed-a-ruby-gosu-game-to-play-in-a-browser) (correct me if I am wrong) but I find some information about different techniques to generate an executable. The problem is that the info I have found is old and/or all over the place:

- https://www.libgosu.org/cgi-bin/mwf/topic_show.pl?tid=445
- https://github.com/gosu/releasy
- https://github-wiki-see.page/m/gosu/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Packaging-on-Windows
- https://github.com/larsch/ocra/

I would like to receive up to date suggestions of what is the best way to generate a shareable version of my Ruby Gosu game nowadays. Extra points if the solution has some macOS support.

Answer (score 2):

### For Windows .exe

Using [ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) worked for me using this command:

```sh
ocra my_ruby_game.rb --windows --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libssp-0.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libgmp-10.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libwinpthread-1.dll
```